# Do arrays have no prototype by default?

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, prototypal-inheritance

I was hoping to be able to augment `Array.prototype` with methods and then call them on any array:

```
>>> [1, 2, 3].customMethod();
```

But it appears arrays have no prototype...?

```
>>> [1, 2, 3].prototype
undefined
```

Am I missing something here?

---

It appears my actual problem lies elsewhere: calling `[1, 2, 3].customMethod()` works, but calling `someDomElement.childNodes.customMethod()` fails. Is `childNodes` not a real array?

```
childNodes.filter is not a function
```

Comment: how about push/pop etc? You are assigning a prototype on an instance, not on the Array type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`prototype` is a property of constructor functions, like `Array`. So `Array.prototype` exists, but not `[1, 2, 3].prototype`; `Array` is a constructor function, while `[1, 2, 3]` is an array.

You are looking for `Object.getPrototypeOf([1, 2, 3])`.

`Object.getPrototypeOf` is an [ECMAScript 5 method](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.3.2), and as such may not be present in all browsers. In which case, you can try accessing the `__proto__` property, i.e. `[1, 2, 3].__proto__`, which is an older, nonstandard thing that `Object.getPrototypeOf` is the new standard version of, or you can use [an ES5 shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) to ensure that wherever `__proto__` is supported, so is `Object.getPrototypeOf`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're working with a DOM NodeList, which is not the same thing as a JavaScript array object.

http://blog.duruk.net/2011/06/19/nodelists-and-arrays-in-javascript/ should provide some insight.

To obtain a 'real' javascript array from an Array-like object (such as a `NodeList` or the `arguments` variable), use the `.slice` method, like so:

```
var realArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(someDomElement.childNodes);
realArray.filter()
```

And yes, like another answer indicated - the `.prototype` object is only a property of the constructor function - not of instances.  eg. `Object.prototype` exists, but `({}).prototype` is undefined.

Comment: +1 for beating me to finding a link to the actual type (`NodeList`). The OP should've asked a new question though because the edit is a completely different question.

Comment: Doesn't `slice` expect at least one parameter, which should be `0`?

Comment: Wait, I can save a step: `Array.prototype.filter.call(someDomElement.childNodes)` :)

Comment: @FredOverflow no, `Array.prototype.slice.call(someDomElement.childNodes)` works just fine.  If you don't pass any extra args to `slice` it just makes a copy of the entire first argument.